# Add printer, connected by USB to my Fritz!box router, to Windows 10 available printers

Tags: networking, router, printer, fritzbox

I have a [Canon TS6052](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_ts_series/pixma-ts6052.html) printer connected by USB to a [FRITZ!Box 5490](https://en.avm.de/products/fritzbox/fritzbox-5490/) router. In the router panel, I see the printer listed.

How do I add the router to Windows so people on the network can print and scan with this printer? I checked guides about adding network printer, but this does not seem to be what I want, since the printer does not have an IP because it is connected over USB and in those guides people connected the printer over WLAN or ETHERNET, which is not the case here.

Comment: Your router should have instructions explaining how to connect to a printer shared via the router.

Comment: OMG thank you so much @K7AAY. I was trying to solve this now for the second time and with the software windows immediately detects the printer no problem. I thought it getting recognized was enough but that's not true. If you make you comment an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your FRITZ!box 5490 router can put a printer or multifunction device into a Windows network without an IP address See FRITZ!Box instructions for this issue at https://en.avm.de/service/fritzbox/fritzbox-7583/knowledge-base/publication/show/13_Connecting-a-USB-printer-to-a-computer-using-the-USB-remote-connection/

You may need their special Remote Connection app which is described at https://en.avm.de/service/fritzbox/fritzbox-7583/knowledge-base/publication/show/74_USB-printer-not-or-occasionally-not-detected-by-FRITZ-Box/

Answer (score 0):

This totally depends on the capabilities of the router. You will have to check the manual.

Some routers share the printer as a SMB printer share (same thing as a shared printer on a Windows computer). Other routers share the printer as an IPP printer device.
In both cases Windows will recognize these as shared printers on the network using the IP address of the router. But you may have to tell Windows explicitly to look for a printer at that IP-address.

If you are really out of luck this will not work at all, because the router can only share USB storage devices (USB sticks and harddrives) and doesn't know what to do with a printer.

Getting the scanner to work in this way is, as far as I know, completely impossible.
Each printer/scanner manufacturer uses its own custom implementation for getting a scanner to work across the LAN (there is no standard method for that), so there is no way a router can know how to deal with your particular model. (Maybe, just maybe, if printer and router are from the same manufacturer.)

In fact: Unless the printer/scanner has a build-in LAN interface (or can be retrofitted with one) there is usually no driver support at all provided for LAN-scanning by the manufacturer. Obviously: if the printer/scanner had build-in LAN capability you wouldn't need to share it via the router.

**EDIT** *after seeing K7AAY's answer, I should include the 1 possibility that I didn't consider earlier and that happens to be a viable solution to your problem:

In my defense: I never encountered or even heard of a router with this capability, even though I use networked USB hubs on a daily basis and they are basically the same thing.*
In some cases a router has the ability to share its USB port as a USB over LAN connection. This requires a special USB over LAN driver to be installed on the computer. This driver connects to the routers USB port via de LAN and presents this locally on the computer as a normal USB port. With this setup ANY USB device can be shared as the router doesn't need to understand the device. It just forwards the USB protocol across the LAN to the client computer. You can even connect a USB hub to such a router and have multiple USB devices plugged in to the hub.
The only drawback is that only 1 computer at a time can use the USB device. (The Fritzbox manual explains that as well.)